# What conclusion can be drawn from smartctl self tests no longer failing on SSD?

Tags: ssd

I have a Samsung 970 EVO SSD that has been used 24/7 for the past 4.5 years, running openSUSE. It's my first SSD, and I'm not sure how well my experience with HDDs translates to SSDs. I replace HDDs at the first error, but I wonder if the same should apply to SSDs.

I never had any issue with my drive, and I expected SMART to tell me if it was about to fail. Anyway, I decided to run a smartctl test, and, to my surprise, it found an address that couldn't be read:

```
smartctl -t long /dev/nvme0n1
smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1

[...]
Num  Test_Description  Status                       Power_on_Hours  Failing_LBA  NSID Seg SCT Code
 0   Extended          Completed: failed segments            11636    742642300     1   7   -    -
[...]
```

After mapping the LBA to the corresponding file, trying to copy the file failed, as expected.

Then I read the whole SSD to get a better idea of how bad the problem is, via

```
dd bs=4k conv=noerror if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=/dev/null status=progress
```

This found its own issues (3 or 4 of them), which didn't include the original LBA. So I tried again to copy the first impacted file and now it worked. Then I ran another test, read the SSD again, ran another test.

Now things seem mostly fine, except that there are a bunch of `Unrecovered Read Error`s, and I'm not sure if anything should be done about them.

There have been 4 impacted files, none of which are really important. For 2 of them I had backups. After the files became available, I ran a comparison and they were identical with their backups.

Last status:

```
# smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1

smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.6.6-1-default] (SUSE RPM)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Samsung SSD 970 EVO 1TB
Serial Number:                      S467NX0KC42742T
Firmware Version:                   2B2QEXE7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 1,000,204,886,016 [1.00 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      4
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          1,000,204,886,016 [1.00 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            718,928,310,272 [718 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 5c81b21b20
Local Time is:                      Wed Dec 27 08:39:23 2023 EET
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x03):         S/H_per_NS Cmd_Eff_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     6.20W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     4.30W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     2.10W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0400W       -        -    3  3  3  3      210    1200
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2000    8000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        33 Celsius
Available Spare:                    96%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    1%
Data Units Read:                    67,636,923 [34.6 TB]
Data Units Written:                 112,642,849 [57.6 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 987,052,850
Host Write Commands:                1,832,390,531
Controller Busy Time:               5,409
Power Cycles:                       141
Power On Hours:                     11,648
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   90
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    53
Error Information Log Entries:      1,180
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               33 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               43 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 64 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS  Message
  0       1180     1  0x33e1  0x4502  0x000    826830178     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
  1       1179    12  0x924d  0xc502  0x000   1536005282     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
  2       1178    12  0x024c  0xc502  0x000   1536005282     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
  3       1177     7  0x2187  0x4502  0x000   1536005282     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
  4       1176    12  0x724b  0x4502  0x000   1417094690     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
  5       1175     1  0x3167  0x4502  0x000   1099791128     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
  6       1174     4  0xe343  0xc502  0x000    888097434     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
  7       1173     4  0x3342  0xc502  0x000    888097436     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
  8       1172     4  0x5341  0x4502  0x000    888097434     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
  9       1171    12  0x91ca  0xc502  0x000    888097436     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
 10       1170    12  0xb1c9  0xc502  0x000    888097436     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
 11       1169    11  0x81a9  0x4502  0x000    888097436     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
 12       1168    10  0x1251  0xc502  0x000    888091288     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
 13       1167    10  0x924f  0xc502  0x000    888091290     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
 14       1166    10  0xb24e  0x4502  0x000    888092344     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
 15       1165    10  0x224d  0x4502  0x000    888091320     1     -  Unrecovered Read Error
... (48 entries not read)

Self-test Log (NVMe Log 0x06)
Self-test status: No self-test in progress
Num  Test_Description  Status                       Power_on_Hours  Failing_LBA  NSID Seg SCT Code
 0   Extended          Completed without error               11644            -     -   -   -    -
 1   Extended          Completed without error               11640            -     -   -   -    -
 2   Extended          Completed: failed segments            11637    832111576     1   7   -    -
 3   Extended          Completed: failed segments            11636    742642300     1   7   -    -
 4   Short             Completed without error               11636            -     -   -   -    -
```

I wasn't able to find a comprehensive page about how to use SSDs, in particular how to prevent errors or deal with them, so here are my questions:

- Should I replace my SSD right away?
- Does it matter that I get an *Available Spare* of 96%?
- Given the test errors are now gone, did it matter that I read the whole SSD? In general, does it do any good to read the whole SSD every once in a while?
- How bad are the *Unrecovered Read Error*s in the *Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01 NVMe Log)*? (The corresponding files that I tested seem OK.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that by continuously reading the disk, the firmware
has, after multiple tries, succeeded in mapping all the bad sectors
to spare ones, so now you have no bad sectors and all your data is readable.

As regarding the 96% available spares, a bit of mathematics:
If the 64 error entries in the log represent recovered sectors
that represent 4% spare capacity, this means that you have in all
1600 spare sectors. This means you still have 1536 spares available.

I would advise to continue paying attention to the SMART data of
the disk, but in my opinion you may continue on using it.
If the number of bad sectors, recovered or not, continues to grow,
then it would be time to replace it.
In the meantime, ensure you have good backups, just in case.

Comment: Thanks! I think it's more than just mapping the bad locations. The data there was somehow read and perhaps copied elsewhere, and an impacted file became readable and quite likely correct. (It was a 7z archive, and I was able to uncompress it without any issue.) But yes, I'll just keep an eye on the drive for now, as I have daily backups and the loss wouldn't be catastrophic.

Comment: My main goal was to get a good understanding of these errors, but I can't say I'm much wiser now. Well, after getting another error I just bought another SSD.